# Armatures, instancing, and RAM use

Tags: rigging, objects, instances

I know that if you have a model duplicated with instancing, that the duplicates do not increase the RAM use when rendering. Does this apply if you have an instanced object where the instances have different armatures or other modifiers deforming them into different shapes?

If you have 500 instances of Object A, that's still only 1 object. But if 250 of those instances have a different rig and pose, is that still only 1 object?

Comment: If you have instanced object, then the modifiers are the same on both (this is the reason why you cannot link the same rigged character twice into another scene). If you have only a mesh instance (2 objects sharing 1 mesh) then this is not the same case as full object instance and it does increase ram usage while rendering (though still not as much as having meshes not instanced).

Comment: Thanks. If you put that as an answer, I will accept it.